# Finding the limit of a function of the form F(g(x), h(x))

Tags: limits

Suppose a function $f$ is defined as:
$$f(x)=F(g(x), h(x))$$

How do we find the limit of $f$ as $x$ approaches some number, say $a$, assuming that the sought limit exists.

Comment: If f is continuous, the limit is $ F(g(a), h(a))$.

Comment: @user99680 , yes, which is also $f(a)$, by definition of continuity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already know that the limit exists, you can do
$$
\lim_{y\to a}\lim_{z\to b}F(y,z)
$$
or
$$
\lim_{z\to b}\lim_{y\to a}F(y,z)
$$
where 
$$
a=\lim_{x\to x_0} g(x),\qquad b=\lim_{x\to x_0} h(x).
$$

Comment: Didn't quite get the notation, how do we find $\lim_{y\to a}\lim_{z\to b}F(y,z)$ ?

Comment: @Shubham: it is $\lim_{z\to b}F(y,z)$ with $y$ fixed, it results in a function of $y$ alone, so get the limit for $y\to a$ of the resulting function.

Comment: Oh, that means treating them separately, as in partial differentiation.